# How to pass a variable from component to component effectively in Angular 14

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a two component. One of them is the main page and other one is a pop-up component. There is a variable in my main page and I want to pass that variable to pop-up. How can I do it without importing the whole main page to pop-up?

I tried to do the method right below but couldn't make it work

```
constructor(
    private service:InvestService,
    private investId:MainPageComponent["investId"]) { }
```

I got the warning below from my IDE but I couldn't make sense of it.

```
No suitable injection token for parameter 'investId' of class 'MainPageComponent'.
  Consider using the @Inject decorator to specify an injection token.
```

Can you help me out please?

Comment: Probably reading [here](https://angular.io/errors/NG2003) you will find the solution to the error you are having. Otherwise write the code of the service you are trying to inject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have the pop up component as a child in your main page and use the input decorator, you can check the documentation here https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs, but here is an example:

(Parent) Main Page Component:ts file

```
fruits: string[] = ['apple', 'banana', 'mango'];
```

html file

```
<h1>List of fruits</h1>
<app-popup [fruits]="fruits"></app-popup>
```

(Child) PopUp Component: ts file

```
@Input() fruits: string[];
```

Now you have a variable called fruits with the values passed from the parent